# Foreach loop for an array of multiple fields form

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a form which users can add or remove multiple input, textarea, select to it.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php if ($buildtemplateexist>0) {?>
<?php $rowNum=0; while ($buildtemplate=mysql_fetch_array($buildtemplatequery)){ $rowNum++; ?>
<?php $bttid=$buildtemplate['CaseTemplateID']; $btstepname=$buildtemplate['StepName']; $btnote=$buildtemplate['Note']; $btmonth=$buildtemplate['Month']; $btday=$buildtemplate['Day']; $btlabel=$buildtemplate['Label']; $bttext=$buildtemplate['Text']; ?>
<?php if (!empty($btstepname)) { ?>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px; border-bottom: 1 solid #ccc; line-height: 40px;" id="form<?php echo $fid; ?>rowNumStep<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>">Step Name/Number: <input type="text" name="stepname[]" size="30" value="<?php echo $btstepname; ?>"> Step Duration: <select name="stepmonth[]" id="sch_hour"><?php for ($y=0; $y<13; $y++) { echo "<option value='$y'"; if ($btmonth==$y) { echo " selected"; } echo ">$y</option>"; } ?></select> Month and <select name="stepday[]" id="sch_hour"><?php for ($r=0; $r<30; $r++) { echo "<option value='$r'"; if ($btday==$r) { echo " selected"; } echo ">$r</option>"; } ?></select> Days<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeStep<?php echo $fid; ?>(<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>);"></div>


<?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($btnote)) { ?>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px;" id="form<?php echo $fid; ?>rowNumTextbox<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>"><div class="activity-description-sentence activity-details-toggle-group-in-list"><p>Note: <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeTextbox<?php echo $fid; ?>(<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>);"></p><div class="feed-note textarea"><textarea name="note[]" id="input_box" class="confirm-cancel autogrowEnabled">Please type your note here ...</textarea></div></div></div>

<?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($btlabel)||!empty($bttext)) { ?>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px;" id="form<?php echo $fid; ?>rowNumInput<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>">Tag Name: <input type="text" name="label[]" size="15" value=""> Tag Description: <input type="text" name="text[]" value="" size="50"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeInput<?php echo $fid; ?>(<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>);"></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px; border-bottom: 1 solid #ccc; line-height: 40px;" id="form<?php echo $fid; ?>rowNumStep<?php echo $rowNum.''.$fid; ?>">Step Name/Number: <input type="text" name="stepname[]" size="30"> Step Duration: <select name="stepmonth[]" id="sch_hour"><?php for ($y=0; $y<13; $y++) { echo "<option value='$y'>$y</option>"; } ?></select> Month and <select name="stepday[]" id="sch_hour"><?php for ($r=0; $r<30; $r++) { echo "<option value='$r'>$r</option>"; } ?></select> Days</div>
<?php } ?>
```

So I use `serializeArray()` to pass it to my php processor.

Here is the php processor:

```
$i=1;

mysql_query("DELETE FROM TemplateDetails WHERE CaseTemplateID='".$_POST['template']."'");
$today = date('Y-m-j');
$output=array();
foreach ($_POST['stepname'] as $key => $value) {



    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO TemplateDetails (CaseTemplateID, StepName, Month, Day, Date, SortField) 
                                    VALUES ('".$_POST['template']."','".$value."','".$_POST['stepmonth'][$key]."','".$_POST['stepday'][$key]."','".$today."','".$i."')")) {

        $i++;
        $newArray=$_POST['stepname'];
        $newCount=count($newArray);
        for ($s=0; $s < $newCount; $s++) { 


        if () {

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO TemplateDetails (CaseTemplateID, Note, Date, SortField) 
                                    VALUES ('".$_POST['template']."','".$_POST['note'][$key]."','".$today."','".$i."')");
                $i++;
                }
                if (preg_match('/label/', $key)){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO TemplateDetails (CaseTemplateID, Label, Text, Date, SortField) 
                                    VALUES ('".$_POST['template']."','".$_POST['label'][$key]."','".$_POST['text'][$key]."','".$today."','".$i."')");
                $i++;
                }   
            }       
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The main problem is how to put the fields in order. I use SortField in my database. but I cannot access to the right sequence of item in the array.

The correct order is what users put, for example, the first field is "Step" and under it, there can be several "Label" or "Note" and after it it can have another "Step" and so on. So it will be a form which sequences are defined by users and we need to know which field was created first so we can show them in a right sequence as user defined

Comment: @Popnoodles: Thank you for your reply. basically, the sequence of fields are important. because after that, i need to show them in order that users made. so when i go to foreach loop, I dont know how to access different items in the array and put them in order. as long as I get access to the items by $_POST['stepname'], I can read only one $_POST['note'][$key] and $_POST['label'][$key], which there might be several of them.

Comment: **Sidenote** In case you don't know, your current code is vulnerable to SQL-injections, unless the form data is validated properly.

Comment: @Popnoodles: the order is what users put, for example, the first field is "Step" and under it, there can be several "Label" or "Note" and after it it can have another "Step" and so on. So it will be a form which sequences are defined by users and we need to know which field was created first so we can show them in a right sequence as user defined.

Comment: @Max: yes I know it. it is not under production yet. we still are facing problems in the very first step if the code works!! :D